# Rust reserved names for modules

Tags: rust

I noticed that I can't name my module `prn`, Cargo refuses to build and I get a rather confusing error message

```rust
mod prn;

fn main() {
}
```

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `prn`
 --> src\main.rs:6:1
  |
6 | mod prn;
  | ^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: to create the module `prn`, create file "src\prn.rs"
```

The file `src\prn.rs` exists, and it is accessible to the compiler.

Changing the name of the module to something/anything else addresses the issue.

Why `prn` is not allowed? Are there any other similar keywords that are forbidden for module names?

(I am using rustc 1.46.0-nightly)

Comment: it's a windows issue

Comment: [Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file: CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. **Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension**; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions) The part in **bold** is missing from the duplicate, and immediately applies to your issue.

Comment: Oh, I see... prn like in printer... those antique reserved msdos names never came to my mind. Thanks for the help!